# HttpServletResponse output desination when called from outside browser

Tags: java, servlets, tcp, tomcat8

I have a Java web application running under Apache Tomcat (8.0.21.0). Its function is to monitor various external processes and display alerts and periodic updated statuses in a browser. The main HTTP request handler is simple enough.

```
public class MyApplication extends HttpServlet
{
.
.
.
    public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        processRequest (request, response);
    }

    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        processRequest (request, response);
    }

    private static void processRequest (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String  strOption = request.getParameter ("option");
        int nOption = Integer.parseInt (strOption);

        response.setContentType ("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter ();

        outputPage (out, nOption);
    }

    private void outputPage (PrintWriter out, int nOption)
    {
        out.println ("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println ("<html>");
        out.println ("<head>");

        switch (nOption)
        {
            // title, style and <body> content depend on option passed in request
            .
            .
            .
        }
        out.println ("</body>);
        out.println ("</html>");
    }
}
```

However, the application also includes a TCP Listener and socket, to receive IoT (Internet of Things) messages:

```
public class MyTCPconnection extends Thread
{
    public Socket clientSocket;    // socket created by listener
    private String url = "[local host address and servlet name]";
    .
    .
    .
    public void run ()
    {
        int RC = 400;    // default value = "Bad Request"
        try
        {
            // get bytes from remote process
            int receiveBufferSize = clientSocket.getReceiveBufferSize ();
            byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[receiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = TCPreceive (clientSocket, receiveBuffer);   // not shown
            if (bytesRead != -1 && bytesRead != 0)
            {
                String strOption = getOption (receiveBuffer);        // not shown
            }

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost (url);
            httpPost.setHeader ("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
            httpPost.setHeader ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            List<NameValuePair> requestParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            reqestParams.add (new BasicNameValuePair ("option", value));

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault ();
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute (httpPost);

            RC = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString (response.getEntity ());
            system.out.println (responseBody);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            RC = 404;
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            RC = 400;
        }

        TCPsend (clientSocket, RC);    // reply to remote process, not shown
    }
}
```

Take for granted that MyTCPconnection.run () generates a valid HTTP request body and submits a POST request to the main application. The problem I have encountered is that, where the POST is made from a web browser (IExplorer, Firefox etc), the application outputs a web page in the browser, but on receiving the POST request from the internal MyTCPconnection instance, it outputs nothing to any browser. Instead, it redirects the entire output to the responseBody.

I thought at first that I merely needed to save the HttpServletResponse and PrintWriter variables from a request from the browser, and pass the saved PrintWriter instance to the function outputPage. However, when I logged these, the results were:

Request from browser:
HttpServletResponse response = org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade@3e1d266b
PrintWriter out = org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter@6bc55aa8

Request from MyTCPconnection.run ():
HttpServletResponse response = org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade@3e1d266b
PrintWriter out = org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter@6bc55aa8

Any hints or hlp would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you think a programmatic HTTP should show some results in a web browser? In this case your other application part is the HTTP client, send the request and get the response. No browser involved.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: when your servlet `MyApplication` receives a request, you want to forward it **internally** to another servlet? For that you have [`ServletResponse#getRequestDispatcher`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher-java.lang.String-), which properly forwards the request, without the need for an external HTTP request.